# Diferença entre árvore binária completa e cheia

Tags: terminologia, algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados

Qual a diferença entre uma árvore binária cheia e uma árvore binária completa?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Definição do Prof. Adriano Cruz da UFRJ que acredito ser bem tranquila de entender:

> Uma árvore estritamente binária é uma árvore binária em que cada nó
>   tem 0 ou 2 filhos.  Uma árvore binária **cheia** é uma árvore em que se um
>   nó tem alguma sub-árvore vazia então ele está no último nível.
>
> Uma árvore **completa** é aquela em se ***n*** é um nó com alguma sub-árvores
>   vazias, então ***n*** se localiza no penúltimo ou no último nível. Portanto,
>   toda árvore cheia é completa e estritamente binária.

Cheia (Full tree)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Completa (Complete tree)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Matheus kkkkkkk , mai se respondeu primeiro... Rápido no gatilho...Nice...

Comment: @MagicHat kkkkkk que coincidência! +Upvote pra você! Respondeu certo chefe :-D

Answer (score 6):

*Tipo assim patrão:*

**Árvore binária cheia** : é uma árvore em que cada nó na árvore tem 0 ou 2 nós filhos(ou folhas).

[image: Árvore Binária Cheia]

**Árvore binária completa** : em uma árvore binária completa todos os níveis, exceto possivelmente o último , está completamente cheia, e todos os nós no último nível são, tanto à esquerda quanto possível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim fica claro entender o termo, "tanto à esquerda quanto possível". Caso contrário, os nós vão se sobrepôr.

Answer (score 3):

Penso que a definição de árvore binária cheia dada pelo MagicHat está incorreta, porque a árvore binária cheia não pode ter nó com zero filhos antes do último nível e a resposta dele deixa aberta esta alternativa, porém a imagem realmente representa uma árvore binária cheia, olha a definição do livro estrutura de dados e seus algoritmos, 2a. Edição de Jayme Luiz Szwarcfiter.
**“Uma árvore binária cheia é aquela em que, se v é um nó com alguma de suas sub árvores vazias, então v se localiza no último nível. Segue-se que toda árvore binária cheia é completa e estritamente binária.”**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi a crítica à resposta anterior. Tem como reforçar com uma imagem?

Comment: imagem inserida, não foi crítica, apenas uma correção, baseado no livro que inclusive estou lendo neste momento.